# Why is my animation fading away?

Tags: rendering, animation, particles

I made a simple particle simulation where a ball produces particles and the ball follows a path. Unfortunately, when I render my project the whole animation fades away **before it is finished**.

I have no idea **why** and **what** to do about it.
The animation flickers for some reason is well... which is bad.

**Here a video:**
https://youtu.be/hp5JPoQF_Sw

[image]

As you can see the particles are fading away.

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=GbVxyY05" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GbVxyY05/) here the file

Comment: it's a donut, are you sure it's the good file?

Comment: just edited it. Sorry :D now it is the correct link

Comment: first thing you have used Time Remapping, it slows down your animation speed, is it what you want? Also, are the Lifetime and Frame End of your Particle System correct? It will make the emission ends at about frame 140...

Comment: All of that should be correct. I wanted to speed down the ball. That is why is used Time Remapping.

Comment: If I go in Properties panel > Particles > Render > Scale and increase the scale you can see particles until frame 138, so I suppose they are  currently too few and too small to be seen around frame 130?

Comment: That is interesting. Before I try it out: Do you still see them in the viewport or in the finished, rendered animation?

Comment: Yes I have some bugs sometimes but I don't know why. Actually I think particles work better if you bake beforehand

Comment: I guess I need to start over again... as you might see, the colors do not work in the final rendered animation. The whole thing is just weird. Thank you for trying to help me! :)

Comment: oh ok it might be because you've assigned a limited time in the particle's material, you should check that, play with the ColorRamp to see if it makes the particles more visible

Comment: yeah oh thanks :D

Comment: So did it fix the problem?